# choose the correct statement .

Tags: linear-algebra

which one is correct ?

Given that   $A= (a_{ij})$ be  a  a $3 \times  3 $ complex  matrix

$a)$ $\det (((-1)^{i+j} a_{ij})) = -\det A$

$b)$ $\det (((\sqrt-1)^{i+j} a_{ij})) = -\det A$

$c)$$\det (((-1)^{i+j} a_{ij})) = \det A$

$d)$  $\det (((\sqrt-1)^{i+j} a_{ij})) = \det A$

I thinks option c) and d) are correct

Is its true ?

Is  its true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix is $3\times 3$, just use the diagonal formula for the determinant:
if $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$, then $\det A =aei +bfg+cdh-gce-hfa-bdi$. So for example for part c) we get that the matrix on the left is is
 $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b & c\\-d&e&-f\\g&-h&i\end{pmatrix}$, and you will find that the determinant is the same as $\det A$. So c) is true. In the same way you can check if the other parts are true or not.